# fail to output expected **argv in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, int **argv)
{    
    int i;   
    printf("argc=%d\n",argc);    
    for (i=0; i<argc; i++)   
    {       
        printf("address argv[%d] = %d\n",i,argv[i]);       
        printf("value   argv[%d] = %d\n",i,*argv[i]);   
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

If I compile this code with executable `test`, and run it with `./test 1 2 3`, then I would expect 4 arguments (`argc`=4) and `*argv[i]` to print my inputs. But it actually outputs these:

```
argc=4
address argv[0] = -517119310
value   argv[0] = 1818570542
address argv[1] = -517119298
value   argv[1] = 3276849
address argv[2] = -517119296
value   argv[2] = 3342386
address argv[3] = -517119294
value   argv[3] = 1146617907
```

So I'm wondering why?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as being caused by a simple typographic error, i.e. basic misunderstanding of the primary function of the language.

Comment: @underscore_d That's not the same as a typo.

Comment: Maybe not purely, but either way, they simply typed something wrong, and so basic a mistake does not make for a very useful question IMO. But maybe I'm wrong and this is actually a great one to have around!

Comment: No, the question is awful. But not because of a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `main()` prototype. second arguement is of `char **` type.

From n1570 section `5.1.2.2.1`

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
       /*..*/
 }
```

Also change `printf()` format specifier accordingly and use `%p` to print the address.

```
for (i=0; i < argc; i++) {       
   printf("address argv[%d] = %p\n",i,argv[i]);       
   printf("value   argv[%d] = %s\n",i,argv[i]); /*just remember argv[i] is char buffer, so use %s */  
}
```

Or if you want to print command line argument char by char

```
for (int i=0; i<argc; i++)  {
    printf("address argv[%d] = %p\n",i,argv[i]);
    for(int j = 0;argv[i][j];j++)
        printf("value   argv[%d][%d] = %c\n",i,j,argv[i][j]);
}
```

Comment: Then they will also need to change its `%d` to `%s` to `prinf()` the argument at each `argv` index. and cast to `(void *)` and use `%p` to print the pointers themselves.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was wrong to put **argv type as an integer. Thank you for correcting me that it's actually a char type.